# Error variable app in a page php (symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use {{app.user.id}} in a page .php but it gives an error message

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: app in D:\wamp\www\AGImm\src\AG\ImmBundle\Controller\AnnonceVenController.php line 46

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity->setIdUser($app->getUser()->getId());
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app` it the instance of `GlobalInstance` class and is specific to templating engine. It is not available to controller (nor services).

You need to rewrite this code:

```
$app->getUser()->getId()
```

into (as I recall, cannot try it now):

```
$this->getUser()->getId()
```

This should work assuming that you have kept `extends Controller` for `AnnonceVenController`